# Create an user without login but that I cant make sudo su with my user

Tags: sudo, users

Do you know if it's possible to create a user without login, for example `userA`?

And then is it possible to become `userA` with my `userB` via

```
sudo su - userA
```

Thanks and sorry my english!

Answer (score 0):

assuming your userB has sudo access, and you mean with "no login" that the login-shell of userA is set to something like `/bin/false`, you would open a shell for userA like this:

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash - userA
```